# Using compression with EJS template engine

Tags: node.js, compression, ejs

I am trying to optimise my site and one of the suggestions I keep getting is to compress response.
I have nodejs app that uses EJS template engine for SSR and can't seem to make it work, and can't find relevant info in docs.

When I send my response back 'normally' ( res.send(something);) it is being compressed.
While when I do ejs.renderFile(...) it doesn't have 'Content-Encoding: gzip' header.

I imported 'compression' module and set app to use it as per docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
res.render(path,data,(error, html) =>{
 if(error)
   ...
 res.send(html)
})
```